# Retrieve keys in LMDB

Tags: scala, lmdb

I wanted to access the key in lmdb from scala code as below:

```
 val file = new File("test.txt")
    val createEnv = create().setMapSize(10485760).setMaxDbs(1)
    val env = createEnv.open(file,MDB_NOSUBDIR)
    val db = env.openDbi(LMDBMain.DB_NAME, MDB_CREATE)
    //define key ,val pair 
    val key = allocateDirect(env.getMaxKeySize)
    val value = allocateDirect(700)
    //insert to db
    key.put("Greeting".getBytes(UTF_8)).flip
    value.put("Hello World".getBytes(UTF_8)).flip
    db.put(key, value)
    //fetching data 
    val txn = env.txnRead
    try {
      val fetchedKey : ByteBuffer = db.get(txn,key)
      val fetchedVal : ByteBuffer = txn.`val`()
      println(UTF_8.decode(fetchedVal).toString())
      println(UTF_8.decode(fetchedKey).toString())
      txn.commit()
    } finally if (txn != null) txn.close()
```

the output is :

```
HelloWorld
```

why I can't see `greeting` in my output !! 
any idea to how I can access key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in every map implementation, for accessing the keys, you need to iterate them:

```
try (CursorIterator<ByteBuffer> it = db.iterate(txn, KeyRange.all())) {
    for (final KeyVal<ByteBuffer> kv : it.iterable()) {
      println(UTF_8.decode(kv.key()).toString())
    }
}
```

You can see more examples in the code examples [here](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/blob/master/src/test/java/org/lmdbjava/TutorialTest.java)